# "По имени" или "по именам"?

Tags: согласование

Как правильнее: "Он зовет по именам своих одноклассников" или "Он зовет по имени всех своих одноклассником"?

Comment: А вот интересно, как еще можно звать одноклассников? Не по отчеству же... По прозвищу? Вопрос не праздный. Если бы, скажем вместо "одноклассников" были "коллеги", можно усмотреть в предложении смысл "относится панибратски", тогда точно "по имени".

Comment: Ну если это мелкие однокласники, лет шести-семи, то между собой они редко используют имена. Прозвища - чаще.

Comment: Прозвища от возраста не зависят. Насколько я помню, у нас они и в старших классах были. А теперь - не знаю. Мой вроде почти не использует. Разве что имя уж очень "просится". Похоже, потерялось у них воображение. Большее значение имеют ники (((  
А этот тип из вопроса, получается, сильно вежливый? Ну, тогда "по именам"!

Comment: В старших классах имена уже наряду с прозвищами. А в младших - им просто тяжело перестоиться. Учителя начинают называть их по фамилиям - именя как бы уходят на второй план. Ну и возрат такой...

Comment: Вы, вижу, большой специалист по младшим школьником. У моего сына в классе я такого не замечала. Кстати, как сказать: в классе, или в классах (он в двух учился)? А учительница их называла, разумеется, по именам. Я, кстати, студентов тоже так зову, когда запомню...

Comment: А у нас в школе все до старших классов звали друг друга по фамилиям. Я такое обращение до сих пор терпеть не могу)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь - "по именам". Все-таки у них не одно имя на всех.
"Каждого одноклассника" было бы "по имени".

Вообще тут, конечно, есть нюанс, "по имени" может иметь наречное значение (дружески, без церемоний): "Он обращался ко всем по имени", но это значение плохо сочетается с "зовет" в данном контексте, так что я предполагаю прямое значение "имени".

Answer (score 1):

Ни один, ни другой вариант не режет слух, но, думаю, предпочтение надо отдать второму варианту, так как у каждого из одноклассников не имена, а конкретное имя